# Input System UI Input Module doesn't work with my old buttons

Tags: user-interface, button, input, module, system

Recently I switched my Unity project to the new input system, the project already had UI buttons and it doesn't work with the new input system.

Here is my inspector of my event system:

[image: Event System Inspector]

and my inspector of my canvas:

[image: Canvas Inspector]

Can you help me ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The new version of Input System to solve my problem, thanks unity.